# iOS Facade Design Pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, facade

I've followed a tutorial which uses the Facade design pattern for retrieving data and displaying on the screen.

- https://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/

This calls an endpoint and when it completes a delegate is used to update the UI with the data that's been retrieved. (Or an error message)

I have an authorisation endpoint I check first, if this is needed, once complete it then calls the action needed, i.e. GetDataForView.

The authorisation token has a limited time, I authorise on first load of the view then use the app, the token expires and I need to re-request a token before I can make another call to another endpoint. The auth delegate method returns authorised but how can I keep track of what action was needing it to know which endpoint to call next?

Would queues be used here?

---

Example

- Call Endpoint #

  - Check if Authorised
- Authorise

  - Authorised

    - Call Endpoint #
  - Unauthorised

    - Show message

Use app

- Want to CallEndpointB, check Auth

  - Authorise

    - Authorised
    - Delegate method Authorised now to call B but how does it know?

Repeat process

- CallEndpointC

**Code**

A

```
//Call A API
- (void)callEndpointA {
  bool authorised = [self checkAuth];
  if (authorised) {
    [self endpointA];
  } else {
    [self authorise];
  }
}
```

B

```
- (void)callEndpointB {
  bool authorised = [self checkAuth];
  if (authorised) {
    [self endpointB];
  } else {
    [self authorise];
  }
}
```

Call the Authorise Endpoint

```
- (void)authorise {
  //Call Auth API
}
```

Delegate retrieves auth success

```
- (void)didReceiveAuth {
  // Call next API based on which endpoint requested.
}
```